# SQL Server: How to change name in a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-express

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008 Express.

How can I change the name of the view? I can change tables' names, but I can't change the view name.

Any suggestion?

Thank you,
Fabio Milheiro

Comment: TODO: Change tags to something like: sql-server sql-server-2005 tsql

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the ALTER VIEW statement something like this :

```
ALTER VIEW dbo.myView
AS
SELECT foo
FROM dbo.bar
WHERE widget = 'foo'
GO
```

[Reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173846.aspx)

To rename a view, use `sp_rename` System Stored Procedure :

```
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.myView', 'myNewViewName'
```

Note: don't include the schema name in the second string, or else you'll get a name like "dbo.dbo.myNewViewName".

Comment: OK, but where do I set the new name of the myView view? Can't find it in the code you posted.

Comment: A word of warning in case of 'sp_rename' - 
`Renaming a stored procedure, function, view, or trigger will not change the name of the corresponding object name in the definition column of the sys.sql_modules catalog view. Therefore, we recommend that sp_rename not be used to rename these object types. Instead, drop and re-create the object with its new name.`

Answer (score 3):

you can use the gui in sms

you can right click view, edit it, then do generate script if you want the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ALTER command or CREATE a new one and delete the old one.

-Shaun